# Using recursion to find the position of the min value

Tags: recursion

I'm studying about recursion. I know the basics, and understand how it works, but ive ran into a snag. I wrote code to find the position of the min value in an array using recursion, which is:

```
 public static int findMinPosition(int[] list, int position)
 {
  int minPosition = 0;
  if(position == list.length)
  {

  }

  else if(position != list.length)
  {
    minPosition = findMinPosition(list, position+1);
    if(list[position] < list[minPosition])
    {

      return minPosition = position;
    }

  }
  return minPosition;
 }
```

This works perfectly, but im not sure how. I understand everything except for `minPosition = findMinPosition(list, position+1);`. I thought this would JUST give the returned value from the method, so i originally also called the method as well, as that is the point of recursion. But it seems all i need is that line of code...so does `minPosition = findMinPosition(list, position+1);` call the method?

Sorry for the rough explanation and any help is useful

Comment: what you have is written in a confusing manner. don't use local variables. pass all state through parameter calls. Best advice would be to get a copy of the Little Schemer and read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that line calls the method.  In words, this says, "Give me the position of the minimum from the *rest* of the list."  You next line compares the first value to that minimum value, and passes the index of the lesser item back to its caller.

You can shorten this a bit by removing structural bloat:

```
public static int findMinPosition(int[] list, int position)
  {
    if (position == list.length)
      return 0

    else
    {
      int minPosition = findMinPosition(list, position+1);
      return list[position] < list[minPosition] ? position : minPosition
  }
```

You could reduce this further by just passing the remaining list on each recursion, rather than the original list and an index.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, that makes more sense. So basically, if you use a variable to get the value of a method, it gives that variable the value, but also will create another iteration of the method?

Comment: Creating another iteration depends on the invocation (function call); whether or not it's assigned to a variable is an independent operation.